# Increment and add value to specific column

Tags: bash, awk

I have some files where I will like to add value in column 3 ( + 2000 ) each time the loop read new file and output new file with changes done in column 3

this is what i try to do

```
  for tt in file file2 file3
    do
    awk '{$3=sprintf("2%06s",$3)} 1'  $tt > file1a
    done
```

Here the inputs and outputs desired.

input1

```
X  9367      211L  36829.00  47705.001 7561 77761  37260.00  47706.00  48136.001
X  9367     1101L  36829.00  47717.001 7771 79921  37260.00  47706.00  48148.001
X  9367     1201L  36829.00  47729.001 7981 82081  37260.00  47706.00  48160.001
X  9367     2491L  36829.00  47741.001 8191 84241  37260.00  47706.00  48172.001
```

output1

```
X  9367    20211L  36829.00  47705.001 7561 77761  37260.00  47706.00  48136.001
X  9367    21101L  36829.00  47717.001 7771 79921  37260.00  47706.00  48148.001
X  9367    21201L  36829.00  47729.001 7981 82081  37260.00  47706.00  48160.001
X  9367    22491L  36829.00  47741.001 8191 84241  37260.00  47706.00  48172.001
```

input2

```
X  8367      211L  36829.00  47705.001 7561 77761  37260.00  47706.00  48136.001
X  8367     1101L  36829.00  47717.001 7771 79921  37260.00  47706.00  48148.001
X  8367     1201L  36829.00  47729.001 7981 82081  37260.00  47706.00  48160.001
X  8367     2491L  36829.00  47741.001 8191 84241  37260.00  47706.00  48172.001
```

output2

```
X  8367    40211L  36829.00  47705.001 7561 77761  37260.00  47706.00  48136.001
X  8367    41101L  36829.00  47717.001 7771 79921  37260.00  47706.00  48148.001
X  8367    41201L  36829.00  47729.001 7981 82081  37260.00  47706.00  48160.001
X  8367    42491L  36829.00  47741.001 8191 84241  37260.00  47706.00  48172.001
```

input3

```
X  7367      211L  36829.00  47705.001 7561 77761  37260.00  47706.00  48136.001
X  7367     1101L  36829.00  47717.001 7771 79921  37260.00  47706.00  48148.001
X  7367     1201L  36829.00  47729.001 7981 82081  37260.00  47706.00  48160.001
X  7367     2491L  36829.00  47741.001 8191 84241  37260.00  47706.00  48172.001
```

output3

```
X  7367    60211L  36829.00  47705.001 7561 77761  37260.00  47706.00  48136.001
X  7367    61101L  36829.00  47717.001 7771 79921  37260.00  47706.00  48148.001
X  7367    61201L  36829.00  47729.001 7981 82081  37260.00  47706.00  48160.001
X  7367    62491L  36829.00  47741.001 8191 84241  37260.00  47706.00  48172.001
```

Comment: You don't actually say what your problem is - is this not working properly?

Comment: OXXO, asking same questions in different posts will not be great, it is better you could frame 1 question and could mention all queries there too.

Comment: ravindersingh13, yes in the previous post was not the loop for the files

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**`Awk`** solution:

```
awk 'FNR==1{ c+=2 }{ $3=sprintf("%d%04d", c, $3); print > FILENAME"_output" }' file1 file2 file3
```

Results:

```
$ head file[123]_output
==> file1_output <==
X 9367 20211 36829.00 47705.001 7561 77761 37260.00 47706.00 48136.001
X 9367 21101 36829.00 47717.001 7771 79921 37260.00 47706.00 48148.001
X 9367 21201 36829.00 47729.001 7981 82081 37260.00 47706.00 48160.001
X 9367 22491 36829.00 47741.001 8191 84241 37260.00 47706.00 48172.001

==> file2_output <==
X 8367 40211 36829.00 47705.001 7561 77761 37260.00 47706.00 48136.001
X 8367 41101 36829.00 47717.001 7771 79921 37260.00 47706.00 48148.001
X 8367 41201 36829.00 47729.001 7981 82081 37260.00 47706.00 48160.001
X 8367 42491 36829.00 47741.001 8191 84241 37260.00 47706.00 48172.001

==> file3_output <==
X 7367 60211 36829.00 47705.001 7561 77761 37260.00 47706.00 48136.001
X 7367 61101 36829.00 47717.001 7771 79921 37260.00 47706.00 48148.001
X 7367 61201 36829.00 47729.001 7981 82081 37260.00 47706.00 48160.001
X 7367 62491 36829.00 47741.001 8191 84241 37260.00 47706.00 48172.001
```

---

Another way is `bash` loop:

```
for f in file[123]; do
    c=$((c+2))
    awk -v c=$c '{ $3=sprintf("%d%04d", c, $3) }1' "$f" > "${f}_output"
done
```

Comment: Roman, it works fine, but the format for output file as changed, How we can keep exactly the same format for output file. Column spaces

Comment: Roman, it works fine, but the format for output file as changed, How we can keep exactly the same format for output file. Column spaces

Comment: @OXXO, add output field separator `OFS='\t'` in any of the following ways: `awk -v OFS='\t' ...` or `awk 'BEGIN{ OFS="\t" }' ....`

Comment: Roman, when i mention to keep exactly the same format for output file. I mean to keep format file for output file same as the one in the input file. The option awk 'BEGIN{ OFS="\t" }' doesn't work in this case

Comment: @OXXO, in Awk: when you change/update some field value - since then you can not retain an arbitrary space gaps between the fields as it was in the initial file